# Unity 2D Platforms Show on Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make a group of platforms appear when colliding with it's trigger?

I would like to walk into the trigger, which will turn on the 'StarPlatforms' in the inspector, revealing every thing that is a child of it. I have only got it to do the exact opposite:

[Before collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHBtY.png)

[After Collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoD4b.png)

[Children of StarPlatfroms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWF9b.png)

**The script on the StarPlatforms**:

```
public class AppearTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject StarPlatforms;

    void Start() {
        StarPlatforms = GameObject.Find("StarPlatforms");
        StarPlatforms.gameObject.SetActive (true);
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            StarPlatforms.gameObject.SetActive (false);

        }               
    }
}
```

I have tried swapping the .SetActives too false then true and it unchecks in the inspector on Play but stays hidden on collision with the trigger.

Thank you for your time.

ps: this is my first go at Unity & C#

Comment: What exactly do you want to show? because the starplatform does not have a object to show, its just a transparant collisional object

Comment: I would like to show everything that is a child of it.

Answer (score 0):

SetActive just sets whether it is part of the main game loop or not. To make a platform invisible or visible use it's Renderer component and deactivate that instead.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It doesnt seem to be working, could it be that not everything in StarPlatforms has a SpriteRenderer ?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to walk into the trigger, which will turn on the
>   'StarPlatforms' in the inspector. I have tried swapping the .SetActives too false then true

You seem to be guessing which one works.  This is how `SetActive` work:

To turn on or activate an object, pass `true` to `SetActive`. To turn it off or deactivate it, pass `false` to it. Also, this should be done in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function not `OnTriggerStay2D`.

The `OnTriggerStay2D` function is called when collision each frame collision is still touching. The `OnTriggerEnter2D` function is called when there is a collision. OnTriggerExit2D is called when there is no longer a collision.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col) 
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Player")) 
    {
        StarPlatforms.gameObject.SetActive (true);
    } 
}
```

If you also want to turn it of or de-activate it when they no longer touch, pass `false` to the `SetActive` function in the `OnTriggerExit` function.

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Player")) 
    {
        StarPlatforms.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    } 
}
```

Not related to your issue but it's a good practice to use `CompareTag` instead of `gameObject.tag`.

Comment: Thank you for the  heads up, so rather not use this method to solve the issue?

Comment: Don't you see the example in my answer? Example on how to activate/de-activate objects where there is collision and after that. It says you should use `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D`. Did you try those?

Answer (score 0):

**This is what worked:**

```
public class AppearTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject[] StarPlatfromArray;

void Start() {
    StarPlatfromArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cave");
    for (int i = 0; i < StarPlatfromArray.Length; i=i+1) {
        StarPlatfromArray [i].gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().enabled = false;
        StarPlatfromArray [i].gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = false;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col) {
    StarPlatfromArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cave");
    for (int i = 0; i < StarPlatfromArray.Length; i++) {
        StarPlatfromArray [i].gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().enabled = true;
        StarPlatfromArray [i].gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = true;
    }

}
```

}